# Strange results from NOT IN subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderId)
FROM SalesOrder
```

It gives a result of 14000

Then I have

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderId)
FROM SalesOrder
WHERE SalesOrderId     IN (SELECT New_DSheetId FROM New_dealsheet)
```

That gives 4169

If I then do

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderId)
FROM SalesOrder
WHERE SalesOrderId NOT IN (SELECT New_DSheetId FROM New_dealsheet)
```

I'm expecting 9831 but the result is 0

Not sure why that is?

Comment: is there a 1:1 relationship between `SalesOrderId` and `New_DSheetId`

Comment: You should always use `not exists (select` instead of `not in (select`

Answer (score 2):

`NOT IN` with `NULL` could be tricky.

Let's unwrap it:

```
col IN (1,2,3, NULL)
<=>
(col = 1) OR (col = 2) OR (col = 3) OR (col = NULL)
```

For now everything is ok. But it isn't. We cannot compare directly value to `NULL` because the result is `unknown`.

Let's check negated condition:

```
col NOT IN (1,2,3,NULL)
<=>
(col != 1) AND (col != 2) AND (col != 3) AND (col != NULL) 
                                              -- here is the problem
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/MMQ12853)**</kbd>

To sum up last condition is always not true. That is why you get 0 records.

---

When you use `NOT IN` make sure that you do not compare with `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(s.SalesOrderId)
FROM dbo.SalesOrder s
WHERE s.SalesOrderId NOT IN
    (
        SELECT n.New_DSheetId
        FROM dbo.New_dealsheet n
        WHERE n.New_DSheetId IS NOT NULL
    )
```