# Check if an ID exists in another table using NOT IN is not working - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to check if some of IDs of a table not exists in another table

Here is full schema and MySQL query I have http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5705b/1

Query I am using is

```
SELECT * from _ayub WHERE a_id NOT IN(SELECT u_id FROM `_umair`)
```

Let say I have `33866326` in `_ayub` but its not in `_umair` but its not showing in final query results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle `NULLs`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _ayub 
WHERE a_id NOT IN(SELECT u_id FROM `_umair` WHERE u_id IS NOT NULL)

-- or
SELECT * 
FROM _ayub 
WHERE a_id NOT IN(SELECT COALESCE(u_id,-1) FROM `_umair`)
```

**[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5705b/2/0)**

Related: [Strange results from NOT IN subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695395/5070879)

Comment: `Let say I have 33866326 in _ayub but its not in _umair but its not showing in final query results` what about that?

Comment: yeah i tried and it gives correct results, but I am asking for explanation :)

Comment: @Umair Added link with expanded expression. The problem is with `sth != NULL`