# Query all remaining results that are not included in the output of another query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have orders in a log table and they can have multiple rows per order_id with different statuses. I want to return a list of orders that have the fallout event, but not with a status of complete. The table looks like:

```
order_number | event | status | capture_id
-------------------------------------------
    1234     | fallout |complete | 95
    1234     | fallout |in progress| 95
    1234     | fallout |Assigned| 95
    1234     | task    |           | 
    2255     | fallout |in progress| 10
    2255     | fallout |Assigned| 10
    2255     | task |         |
```

In this table the query would return order_number 2255

I queried a list based on capture_id, because capture_id can have multiple values for the same order_number. The capture_id corresponding to fallout will stay the same throughout the order though in this case 95 and 10.

```
SELECT* FROM RECORDS
WHERE event = 'fallout' and status  LIKE 'complete'
order by created desc;
```

^ That returns all rows that are complete

```
  SELECT * FROM  RECORDS
  WHERE capture_id NOT IN
   (SELECT capture_id FROM records
   WHERE event = 'fallout' and status  LIKE 'complete')
   order by created desc;
```

^That is my attempt at querying the remainder of the capture_id which currently returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *^That is my attempt at querying the remainder of the capture_id which currently returns nothing*

Fixing code with proper null handling

```
SELECT *
FROM RECORDS
WHERE capture_id NOT IN
   (SELECT capture_id FROM records
   WHERE event = 'fallout' and status  LIKE 'complete' and capture_id IS NOT NULL)
order by created desc;
```

More:  [Strange results from NOT IN subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695395/5070879)

Comment: The first one I don't think will work because 'complete' is used for other events as well that also produce capture_id. I will try your code fix.

Comment: @RanchDubois OK, I assumed that capture_id is unique in your table. Second approach will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks for this code fix, so the query is returning the orders I need without a complete status on fallout events, but I don't know why event = 'fallout' isn't filtering out other results, because I am still getting other events mixed in with the results, just just the fallout events.

Comment: Nevermind, I just added another AND clause on the result and have it sorted. Thank you!